# Ordered pair combinations based on two different sets

Tags: combinatorics

I'm very confused about this problem. Let's say we have an ordered pair $\langle B, C\rangle$, where $B$ and $C$ are sets that $ B,C\subseteq A$, $|B|=|C|=2$ and $B\cap C= ∅$. And $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}, |A|=6$. Our goal is to find the quantity of all available ordered pairs of that type.

Combinatorics are really confusing me, so I decided to divide the problem to steps.

For $B$ there should be ${{6 \choose 2}}=15$ combinations. For $C$, since we have already took two items from $A$ and put them in $B$, we will have ${{4 \choose 2}}=6$ combinations. Now, the ordered pair  $\langle B, C\rangle$ will have $15 ⋅ 6=90$ combinations.

That's my problem here. I'm not sure if my approach is correct (especially when dealing with the **ordered pair**), since there are a lot of confusing formulas to calculate combinations, permutations e.t.c.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Is $|A|=6$? or where does this $6$ comes from? If so, you are correct! The ordered pair comes from the fact that when you choose $B$ and then $C$ you are giving them an explicit order.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention. |A| = 6.

Answer (score 0):

The size of A is really irrelevant. If |B|= 2 B contains two objects.  We can label the "a" and "b".  If |C|= 2 C contains two objects.  We can label them "c" and "d".  Since B and C are disjoint there are 4 separate objects.  There are a total of 2x2= 4 combinations:
(a, c), (a, d), (b, c), and (b, d).

Comment: Thanks. But I forgot to mention some info about the set A. I think it is relevant.